# Compare missing rows in sheet2 from sheet1 and show them in sheet3 with condition

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Sample test sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B9ESm5JFdHF9U5m2gBKriohS_CUDnt7CvBQwiWbjeAw/edit?usp=sharing

I have 2 sheets: population and contacted which are both manually populated by a user. I want to compare all the missing ID in contacted that are not in population, with a condition that only people with status that contains alive to show up in the 3rd sheet aka "need to contact" sheet. It is assumed that only people who are alive are added to contacted sheet so there is no need to validate if a person is alive if it is present in contacted sheet.

The current formula I am using is `=ArrayFormula(FILTER(Population!A2:B,ISERROR(match(IF(REGEXMATCH(Population!C2:C,"Alive"),Population!A2:A,""),Contacted!A2:A,0))))`

It is showing all the rows not in contacted but it in the population sheet, the problem I am having is only trying to print out the people alive so for my sample sheet there only needs to be 2 rows present in my needs to contact sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=FILTER(Population!A2:B800, NOT(COUNTIF(Contacted!A2:A800,Population!A2:A800)), 
 REGEXMATCH(Population!C2:C800, "(?i)alive"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. It is very close to what I need. I wanted to only output IDs 5481 and 2367 because 2377 is already in the "Contacted" sheet. Ill try testing out variations of the formula you used and see if I can get it to work. I think I explained it poorly and you might have solved it this way because of the way I explained my problem.

Comment: Solved the problem perfectly as needed. Appreciate it a lot!